# Hw create Gradient in android

Tags: android, xml

How I can in android make this gradient with xml.

[image]

Please help me create that xml

Comment: check it http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/06/gradient-drawable-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on you project and create a new folder. Name it drawable.
2. Right click on drawable folder, New -> Android XML file and give it any name
3. Paste this in the file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <gradient
   android:startColor="#1c4f8c"
   android:endColor="#2e6eb8"
   android:angle="90" />

   </shape>
   ```

To use set the drawable file as background

Answer (score 0):

To create gradient in android open your project, right click on your drawable folder and create a new file name it whatever you want with .xml extension. In this case i will name the file myGradient.xml

Open myGradient.xml and copy paste the code. Change the color values to fit how you would like your gradient to appear

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:bottom="6px" android:right="4dp">

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#d7009482"
            android:endColor="#ad1c4e9b"
            android:centerX="100%"
            android:centerY="150%"
            android:type="linear"
            android:angle="135"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

That's it the output for about is as shown below
[gradient color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tREeY.png)

To use the gradient you only need to declare it as background in your view.

```
android:background="@drawable/myGradient"
```

Hope that helps